# Twilio Conversations API || Post-Event URL Be Dynamic to the Conversation SID

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-conversations

I have the Pre-Event Url correct which will send a POST request to add everything i need. But I need to try to get a dynamic url for the Post-Event URL, when I want to view the conversation, for example:

```
https://example.com/conversation/<Conversation_sid>/
```

I can put a wildcard after the conversation url:

```
https://example.com/conversation/*
```

But I would like to see if its possible to go by the conversation sid, since i will then be be adding new mesages and recieving new ones from that url when conversing.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Post Action webhooks include the `ConversationSid` as a request parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/conversations-webhooks#post-action-webhooks) for all webhooks that are relevant to a conversation.

You cannot setup the webhook URL to include the `ConversationSid`, so instead you should parse it out of the request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass in the `ConversationSid` using a post request using a hidden value of the ConversationSid to set the url route parameter.